# Tracing an HTTP request in Go in a one structured log line

Tags: http, go, logging, trace

I have learned you can "decorate" the HTTP transport so that you can details of the request, however I can't quite figure out how you log the URL in the same line.

https://play.golang.org/p/g-ypQN9ceGa

results in

```
  INFO[0000] Client request            dns_start_ms=0 first_byte_ms=590 response_code=200 total_ms=590 url=
  INFO[0000] 200
```

I'm perpetually confused if I should be using https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue to pass around the context in a struct, especially in light where https://blog.golang.org/context-and-structs concludes with **pass context.Context in as an argument**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `r.RequestURI` by `r.URL.String()` in your code to log the full, valid URL (https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String). `RequestURI` is empty on the client side (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request), as the output from your code is showing.

I don't see how `context.Context` relates to your question, but I believe https://blog.golang.org/context-and-structs is considered "best practice".

Answer (score 5):

Go through the behaviour of how the request is constructed in [request.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=28704:28805#L843) from net/http. You see that the `RequestURI` field is never set there. Quoting from same [reference](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=28704:28805#L287),

> Usually the URL field should be used instead.
> It is an error to set this field in an HTTP client request

So, I would suggest you to use `request.URL` instead.
It is a parsed from the request uri. It should have the data you need.

You can construct the output as following:

```
f := log.Fields{
    "url": fmt.Sprintf("%s %s%s", r.Method, r.URL.Host, r.URL.Path),
}
```

Also, in my experience, it is far more easier to use [context.WithValue](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) and pass the context as an argument.

Comment: The url is `r.URL.String()`, no need to construct anything with `fmt.Sprintf`.

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf` is needed to get the http method - which is important as routes react differently based on the method in use. But yes `r.URL` contains the full URL.